# How to disable caret blinking in textboxes in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I tried to Google this and I only found results related to some bug years ago that makes the cursor blink even outside of textboxes. I don't have that problem, I'm trying to deactivate caret blinking in textboxes.

The only idea related to that I found was to set ui.caretblinktime to 0, but that setting doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 4):

> The only idea related to that I found was to set ui.caretblinktime to 0, but that setting doesn't exist anymore.

You have to create the config key yourself.

Visit `about:config`, then enter `ui.caretBlinkTime` into the config search bar, add it (plus symbol button) as a Number type and set the value to zero.

Worked for me on Firefox 76.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/cnt7qp/how_to_adjust_cursor_blink_rate_in_webkit_not/ewe53db/

Comment: This totally changed my life, Firefox finally feels usable. One thing to note is that the setting is case-sensitive: `ui.caretBlinkTime` will do the trick. (I also set `ui.caretWidth` to `2`.)

Comment: @DanielP.Shannon You are right! I have updated the answer with the corrected, case-sensitive preference name.